# What's the meaning of Python error message `KeyError: 'The grouper name created_at is not found'`?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, pandas-resample

I'm trying to take a series of tweets and group them into 1 hour intervals based on when the tweets were created, and sum the likes the tweets got for each 1 hour interval.

The tweets have been converted to a pandas dataframe, eg:

```
df.head(1)
    author_id   username    author_followers    author_tweets   author_description  author_location text    created_at  lang    tweet_id    retweets    replies likes   quotes
0   2395138046  WorldCoinIndex  12832   46121   Cryptocurrency index | prices | 24hr volume | ...   None    Cryptocurrencies $ETH $LTC $DASH $XMR $ZCASH h...   2022-02-11 23:59:38+00:00   en  1492287240990507009 0   1   0   0
```

**EXPECTATION**

The code i'm applying to the above dataframe:

```
df.likes.resample('H', on='created_at').sum()
```

My understanding is `likes` specifies the column to be summed, 'H' specifies the 1 hour time intervals, and the `on` parameter defines the time series key `created_at`. based on the time series key parameter `created_at`.

**RESULTING ERROR MESSAGE**

> KeyError: 'The grouper name created_at is not found'

**ASSESSMENT**

When I search that error message, I see mostly references for the `groupby` method, which I considered, but figured Time Series would be simpler.

Shouldn't it return an index error if it's the 'created_at' parameter that's problematic?

Answer (score 1):

Based on documentation:

> on str, optional For a DataFrame, column to use instead of index for
> resampling. Column must be datetime-like.

When you use the .likes actually there is no column with the specified name on the column you try to sample over.
Example:

```
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=9, freq='T')
df = pd.DataFrame({'likes': range(9), 'user':['ali' for i in range(9)]}, index=index)
df['create on'] = df.index
```

This produce the error:

```
df.likes.resample('3T', on = 'create on').sum()
```

And the right way:

```
df.resample('3T', on = 'create on').sum()
```

the output:

[image]

Comment: Something like `df.resample('3T', on='created_at')['likes'].sum()` is more likely what OP is looking for. As without specifying the column (or columns) pandas will try apply `sum` to all columns in the DataFrame which is likely to fail given all of the different column types in the shown sample data.

Comment: @HenryEcker it sums numeric only data, why would it fail? In fact \@keramat's data has nonnumerics and it works

Comment: @does it matter, he means with main question example.

Comment: @keramat doesnT matter

Comment: @does it matter, You are right, but I prefer to restrict the result as much as possible.

Comment: @keramat yeah you're not doing that currently. my objection is to failure not to what to keep and not.